# How to get the expression of a special function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, curated-data, entity

How to get the expression of a special function? Like gamma function:

```
 Gamma[z]=Integrate[t^(z-1)/e^t, {t, 0, Infinity}]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
reps = Entity["MathematicalFunction", "Gamma"][
  "IntegralRepresentations"]
```

[image]

```
reps[[2]][z]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Activating all except `Integrate`

```
Activate[reps[[2]][z], Except[Integrate]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For some functions, many of the properties may be missing. For example, for [`Hypergeometric2F1`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric2F1.html)

```
properties = Select[
   Entity["MathematicalFunction"]["Properties"],
   FreeQ[
     Entity["MathematicalFunction", "Hypergeometric2F1"][#],
     Missing] &];

Length /@ {Entity["MathematicalFunction"]["Properties"], properties}

(* {54, 7} *)

Manipulate[
   Entity["MathematicalFunction", 
       "Hypergeometric2F1"][prop], 
   {{prop, EntityProperty["MathematicalFunction", 
         "WolframFunctionsSiteLink"], "properties"}, 
     properties}]
```

[image]

In this case, the most useful available properties are the `RelatedFunctions` and `Wolfram Functions Site link`

Comment: Thank you very much! @Bob Hanlon

Comment: Hello, could you tell me how to express the function Hypergeometric2F1? I don't know which code to use for Hypergeometric2F1, such as "IntegralRepresentations" for Gamma.

Comment: @lotus2019 - see edit.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for your help!